# Concatenation in C

Tags: c

I have a program which does concatenation.

its like char *testConc(int a,..)
Where a indicates number of arguments are being passed for concatenation.
As legth keeps on changing is there is anything like constructor overloading in C

or any simple syntax which implements the functionality

Comment: What do you mean the length keeps changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C does not have function overloading capabilities. The syntax you have is called a [variadic function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdarg.h.html), which can be used to perform what you asked.

The textConc function would look something like this:

```
char *textConc(int argc, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    char *str = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    va_start(args, argc);
    while (argc--)
    {
        /* next string */
        const char *temp = va_arg(args, const char *);
        size_t size = strlen(temp);
        /* make room and copy over */
        str = realloc(str, len+size+1);
        memcpy(str+len, temp, size+1);
        /* new length */
        len += size;
    }
    va_end(args);

    return str;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *example = textConc(4, "Hello", "All", "good", "morning");
    puts(example);
    free(example);
    return 0;
}
```

If you use GCC, we can fake overloading completely, using a little help of macros.

Rename textConc to textConcN and use the following macros:

```
#define ARGCOUNT(...)  (sizeof((const char *[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(const char *))
#define textConc(...) textConcN(ARGCOUNT(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* notice, no more need for the number of arguments */
    char *example =  textConc("Hello", "All", "good", "morning");
    puts(example);
    free(example);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your solution was veryhelpful Wiz, but in line  const char * temp = va_arg(args, const char * );    it says syntax error 'const'.I am using cl to compile.

Comment: @kittu vs cl? compiled fine for me?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are [varadic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

/* print all non-negative args one at a time;
   all args are assumed to be of int type */
void printargs(int arg1, ...)
{
  va_list ap;
  int i;

  va_start(ap, arg1); 
  for (i = arg1; i >= 0; i = va_arg(ap, int))
    printf("%d ", i);
  va_end(ap);
  putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
   printargs(5, 2, 14, 84, 97, 15, 24, 48, -1);
   printargs(84, 51, -1);
   printargs(-1);
   printargs(1, -1);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions can't be overloaded in C.

You could rewrite your function as `char *testConc(const char *s, ...)`, where you mark the end of the list with `NULL`:

```
testConc("foo", "bar", "baz", "quux", (char *)0);
```

This makes adding changing the number of actual arguments easier.  If you have a C99 compiler, you can even write a wrapping macro that adds the `NULL` for you:

```
#define TESTCONC(...) testConc(__VA_ARGS__, (char *)0)
```

Comment: Program flow is like this.In main program i ll pass testConc(2,"good","morning"),where integer 2 indicates i am passing three, or i may pass testConc(4,"Hello","All","good","morning") where 4 for 4 agguments.I need help in writing subroutine for concatenation whose definition is char *testConc(int a,..)and number of arguments are not fixed.